# gitk on bare directory

Tags: git, gitk

I used to be able to run **gitk** on bare directory on remote server.

I got a new Win10 machine, installed git from git-scm .com That gave me git and git Bash.
Now when I go to the same remote server

```
 MINGW64 /t/git/MyProject (BARE:master)$ gitk
```

> gitk says *fatal: this operation mus be run in a work tree*

I kind of understand what's going on, and yes I can do `$ git log`

But why did it work before?

Comment: There are drop-in alternatives to `gitk`. For example: `git-dag` and `gitg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why did it work before?

A recent change in the behavoir of git

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

broke gitk. This can be found wehn following down the [original bug report](https://lore.kernel.org/git/4e2e5829-b9a7-b9b4-5605-ac28e8dbc45a@onlinehome.de/).

I recommend downgrading to version 2.24.1.windows.2 which is the most recent that doesnt have it.

Comment: At my work with Windows 10, gitk works on a bare repository - sometimes. e.g. for our 75 repos on this remote server, ~40-50 work with gitk with the others reporting this message above

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> gitk says fatal: this operation mus be run in a work tree
> ```

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "`gitk`" should fix this issue when run in a bare repository.

See [commit a99bc27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a99bc27aec74071aa1e9ecaa12c642e88e377165) (15 Dec 2019), and [commit f177c49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f177c49a97d16aab490aa34fa52e113c21de4a1f) (02 Nov 2019) by [Роман Донченко (`SpecLad`)](https://github.com/SpecLad).
See [commit 2faa6cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2faa6cdc5e4d1d5fd27512994f002fc2640b1949) (09 Apr 2020) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
See [commit 113ce12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/113ce1243f0bcd870b24ff22aca212575027f79f) (11 Feb 2020) by [Stefan Dotterweich (`stefandtw`)](https://github.com/stefandtw).
See [commit c1a6345](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1a63459ed7364bb03e0549c1f042bca469d278f) (15 Oct 2019) by [Eric Huber (`echuber2`)](https://github.com/echuber2).
See [commit d4247e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4247e06027da5b3ac299fbba3a7443a919ca0ff) (07 Dec 2019) by [Kazuhiro Kato (`kkato233`)](https://github.com/kkato233).
See [commit b8b6095](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8b60957ce91b237b7f8925a3126b2662d3fcf41) (12 Dec 2019) by [Beat Bolli (`bbolli`)](https://github.com/bbolli).
See [commit e2b9cb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2b9cb1c5a45290f568681862fb27714d6e4e52b) (03 Oct 2020), and [commit e272a77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e272a77964d95e2fd8b3b47b7f3840ed3e42b81c) (23 Jan 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 6cd8049](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cd80496e9d3694825ec941663b65c9516102289) (03 Oct 2020) by [Paul Mackerras (`paulusmack`)](https://github.com/paulusmack).
See [commit e244588](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e244588eb6ceef86a6a183b3bb032960e26033bb) (10 Sep 2020) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0cf28f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cf28f6d4775ca304e3e2028c2645c600e869641), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`gitk`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e272a77964d95e2fd8b3b47b7f3840ed3e42b81c): be prepared to be run in a bare repository
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Paul Mackerras</sup>

> [784b7e2f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/784b7e2f25ce2a812d6b2dcbe4d3a2ea93484bb4) ("`gitk`: Fix "External diff" with separate work tree", 2011-04-04, Git v1.7.9-rc0) added an unconditional call to "[`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0cf28f6d4775ca304e3e2028c2645c600e869641/Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt#L264-L266)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-toplevel))</sup>" to set up a global variable quite early in the course of the program, so that the location of the working tree can later be known if/when the user chooses to run the external diff via the `external_diff_get_one_file` proc.
> Before that change, the external diff code used to assume that the parent directory of "`.git`" directory is the top-level of the working tree.
>
> Recent versions of [`git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e272a77964d95e2fd8b3b47b7f3840ed3e42b81c/Documentation/git-.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-))</sup> however notices that "`rev-parse --show-toplevel`" executed in a bare repository is an error, which makes `gitk` stop, even before the user could attempt to run external diff.
>
> Use the `gitworktree` helper introduced in [65bb0bda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65bb0bda75f4070a609d266d7231b4ec53d56972) ("`gitk`: Fix the display of files when filtered by path", 2011-12-13, Git v1.7.10-rc3 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b476064544b9a64d062acc5e3c6be831ebb721cb)), which is prepared to see failures from "`rev-parse --show-toplevel`" and other means it tries to find the top-level of the working tree instead to work around this issue.
> The resulting value in `$worktree` global, when run in a bare repository, is bogus, but the code is not prepared to run external diff correctly without a working tree anyway ;-)